# Compiler constant indicating memory alignment requirement

Tags: c, portability, platform, memory-alignment

Some CPU architectures (other than x86) dislike reading and writing multibyte numbers at unaligned addresses so much that they raise SIGBUS exception upon detecting this and forcing the programmer to do everything manually on a byte-wise order. While nothing probably can be done with platforms that require this, it would be stupid to check for alignment and perform byte-wise operations on platforms that allow unaligned access (such as x86). The question is: **do C/C++ compilers define a constant that indicates alignment requirement**?

Currently, I'm using this:

```
#if defined(_M_IX86) | defined(__i386) | defined(__i386__) | defined(i386) | defined(_X86_)
    // Unaligned access is allowed.
#elif defined(_M_X64) | defined(__x86_64__) | defined(__x86_64) | defined(__amd64) | defined(__amd64__) | defined(_M_AMD64)
    // Unaligned access is allowed.
#else
    #define ALIGNED_ACCESS_ONLY
#endif
```

But it looks too “home-brew”: rather than indicating the actual properties of current hardware platform, it only depicts my own considerations about x86-32 and x86-64 and the most popular constant names for these platforms.

Comment: The obvious solution would be catching `SIGBUS` upon trying an unaligned access...

Comment: @black That would be *heavy*, I suppose: even if catching a hardware exception was fast (which I strongly doubt), anyway installing a handler, catching the error and removing the handler never could be as fast as simply checking for address alignment and then branching accordingly. Unaligned access in my case is the primary mode of operation rather than a rare situation.

Comment: It is indeed; I just proposed the "poor's-man-solution" to that. Could you tell us whether you just want to know that or you're trying to solve a specific problem [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @black There is absolutely no hidden task beyond reading / writing numbers and other primitive objects from / to a buffer, perhaps changing byte order on-the-fly as needed.

Comment: "it would be stupid to check for alignment and perform byte-wise operations on platforms that allow unaligned access (such as x86)"  Is it actually stupid?  I know x86 allows unaligned accesses, but I thought you pay a substantial performance penalty when you actually perform an unaligned access, so avoiding them doesn't necessarily seem stupid.  If the values are often unaligned, then a byte-by-byte solution would be portable and possibly no worse in performance.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Native CPU instructions are always faster than your code or at least not slower, — even when penalized by performance-killing circumstances, because your code will be penalized as well. The only hope you can have is that out-of-order execution will reduce the difference, but it will never make your custom code to run faster than a native read / write operation.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov:  I didn't say it would be faster.  I said it would be "possibly no worse in performance."  Ideally, you shouldn't have unaligned data.  If the unaligned values you're accessing are contiguous, you might consider using memmove to align them before accessing.  Then you get speed and portability, freeing you from worrying about platform-specific details.

Answer (score 1):

*I am not technically answering the question you posed, but I am proposing a workaround in case the answer to your question is no.*

If your code is compiled with the help of a configure script, you can test to see if aligned access is required.  GNU autoconf has a feature for doing this:

http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_aligned_access_required.html

Basically it compiles the following small program, runs it, and looks at the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char* string = malloc(40);
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < 40; i++)
  {
    string[[i]] = i;
  }

  {
     void* s = string;
     int* p = s+1;
     int* q = s+2;

     if (*p == *q) { return 1; }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: would be lovely if you `free`d the memory, but plus one.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code came from GNU autoconf and I only added some whitespace and brackets to make it clear what was inside the for loop.  You could send a patch to them I suppose.

Comment: DavidGrayson: Any particular reason they're not just stack-allocating `string`? And @Bathsheba: I know some people will hate me for saying this, but GNU have never been known for code quality.

Comment: I suppose that on some architectures, the instructions for reading data from the stack could be special and have different alignment requirements.  That's just a guess though.

Comment: @Bathsheba, why waste time `free()`-ing when you can just quit?! The kernel will get the memory back either way.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't require any check for that is one I've seen in an implementation of `memcpy`. Basically, you start copying data byte per byte till you get to an address multiple of the desired alignment.
After that, you can start copying word-size chunks of data with all the benefits you have with an aligned address (loop unrolling, vectorization, ...).

You'll get the best out of it with large blocks of data, though.

Apparently, neither `clang` nor `gcc` define any macro to inform about unaligned access. (`gcc/clang -E -dM - < /dev/null -march=native`).
Some ideas you may want to consider:

- Reduce the need in the first place: problems incur when you use pointers. Try to avoid that, refactoring the way you handle your data.
- `asm`: write platform-dependent `asm` to load/store to/from an unaligned access, although it highly depends on the platforms you're working with.
- SSE allows unaligned access.

Comment: I am reading / writing a single number at a time, even when some numbers are occasionally grouped into arrays (and even in this case, they are all unaligned most of the time).

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Added a few other options. However, it's still hard to extract possible solutions without *real* code available.